# Display check boxes inside flash list control CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I would like to implement check boxes inside flash list control using Flash Pro CS6. I literally follow example provided by Adobe at [Work with a CellRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd4.html). The only code in my .fla file is:

```
myList.setStyle("cellRenderer", CustomCellRenderer); 
myList.addItem({label:"Burger -- $5.95"}); 
myList.addItem({label:"Fries -- $1.95"});
```

and the only code in the CustomCellRenderer.as file is (copy-paste from the Adobe example):

```
package 
{ 
    import fl.controls.CheckBox; 
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer; 
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ListData; 
    public class CustomCellRenderer extends CheckBox implements ICellRenderer { 
        private var _listData:ListData; 
        private var _data:Object; 
        public function CustomCellRenderer() { 
        } 
        public function set data(d:Object):void { 
            _data = d; 
            label = d.label; 
        } 
        public function get data():Object { 
            return _data; 
        } 
        public function set listData(ld:ListData):void { 
            _listData = ld; 
        } 
        public function get listData():ListData { 
            return _listData; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

When I test movie I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.controls::CheckBox/drawLayout()
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
    at fl.controls::List/drawList()
    at fl.controls::List/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. The author of similar question [Display checkbox inside Flash List Control ? (Similar to item rendering in Flex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356445/display-checkbox-inside-flash-list-control-similar-to-itemrendering-in-flex) does not seem to have this problem - his problem is just in multiple selection functionality.

**ANSWER (can not post answers for another 8 hour but eager to close the issue) Figured out myself: CheckBox component must be present in the library. Go to menu Window->Components-> Double click CheckBox. Check box will appear on the stage and in the library. Remove check box from the stage. Test movie.**

Answer (score 0):

Drag an instance of CheckBox component onto the stage then delete off the stage.